# template syntax for related data

Tags: ember.js

This seems like it should be simple. Suppose I have the following model:

```
App.Folder = DS.Model.extend({
    folder_id: DS.attr('number'),
    folder_name: DS.attr('string'),
    items: DS.hasMany('App.Item')
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    item_id: DS.attr('number'),
    folder_id: DS.attr('number'),
    item_name: DS.attr('string'),
    folder: DS.belongsTo('App.Folder')
});
```

...and the following data:

```
App.Folder.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        folder_name: 'My First Folder',
        items: [100]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        folder_name: 'Another Folder',
        items: [101]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        folder_name: 'Folder 3',
        items: [102]
    }
];

App.Item.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 100,
        folder_id: 1,
        item_name: 'This is an item'
    },
    {
        id: 101,
        folder_id: 2,
        item_name: 'A cleverly named item'
    },
    {
        id: 102,
        folder_id: 3,
        item_name: 'This one is also an item in a folder'
    }
];
```

Now, in my "item" template, shouldn't I be able to do something like this to show the folder related to an item:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="snapshot">
          <div class="row-fluid property-row-alt">
            <div class="span4 property-label">item name:</div>
            <div class="span8">{{ item_name }}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid property-row">
            <div class="span4 property-label">folder:</div>
            <div class="span8">{{ folder.folder_name }}</div>
          </div>
</script>
```

"**folder.folder_name**" is the key syntax I'm trying to nail down here. Maybe this isn't possible, but I'm hoping to get the related folder and drill down into it's folder_name inside my item template.  Can I do this in Ember?  Using the latest versions.

Comment: Hard to say without details of your Route and Controllers. This template looks like partial?, so the context of the parent controller would determine what bindings are available in it. If you have a `folder` binding available in your controller the `folder.folder_name` will work.

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar Yes this is a partial template. So my question I then is how to have both Folder and Item bindings available in a single template. Is that possible? Or do I need to flatten the relationship by adding for example "folder_name" as a property on the Item model?

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar -- I finally realized I just wasn't getting the centrality of the router and controllers in Ember. Your comment did help point me in the right direction.  Thanks for the help.